# Angular 2: routerLink not resolving

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

- Angular Version: 2.1.0
- Router Version: 3.1.0

I am learning routing in Angular 2 and the custom segments are not being appended to the URL when clicking the link nor does the component load.

Manually typing in the segments into the address bar does work and the component loads in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` but instead of this I want it to work as expected - by clicking the link inside the `routerLink` directive.

I have followed the router [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and am still having ill results.

Here is a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082983/angular-2-routerlink-not-resolving-in-browser) but have come to find no solutions that work for me as of yet.

The two common solution I have come across are:

- Misspelling 'routerLink' which is case sensitive
- Not having `<base href='/'>` at the top of `index.html`

Also there are no errors in the console window in Chrome

So before continuing I just wanted cancel out the obvious solutions.

This is what I have done to configure my custom router:

**1. Config custom routes (routes.ts)**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipesComponent } from './recipes/recipes.component';
import { ShoppingListComponent } from './shopping-list/shopping-list.component';

//TODO Fix routing bug (not switching on click or displaying in URL)
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent},
    {path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent}
];

/*Set routing up for root of app*/
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**2. Import routes globally (app.module.ts)**

```
import { routing } from './routes';//Custom routes file

    @NgModule({                     
      // Declarations removed for bravity
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
      ],
      providers: [ShoppingListService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent,]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**3. Supply the RouterOutlet Directive (app.component.html)**

```
<rb-header></rb-header>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**4. Implement routerLink with static segments (header.component.html)**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a routerLink="/recipes">Recipes</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/shopping-list">Shopping List</a></li>
</ul>
```

The router [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) says that using `routerLink` is for static segments and `[routerLink]` is for using params to pass. I have tried both approaches but they still pose the same outcome.

Comment: You are probly getting an exception, because I can't see you importing this components anywhere. You should create a module for those and import it at the main AppModule

Comment: Did you compile your ts files into js files? Do you have any errors?

Comment: @echonax thatnks for asking - No, there are no errors and I have added that to my question

Comment: Hmm why isn't your router module inside an `@NgModule`?

Comment: everything looks fine to me. Not sure but try - `routerLink="recipes"`

Comment: @echonax RouterModule is imported into routes.ts which is imported inside NgModule in app.module.ts

Comment: @ShadowCore I don't know if it was like that in 2.1 but router module needs to be an `@NgModule` too

Comment: I think you should create a plunker, I couldn't replicate ur issue

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved the problem.

**What was the cause ?**

An unrelated bug inside one of my `component.html` where there was a property that was assigning a string to an unknown property of 'name' - Angular 2 compiled the string interpolation before a 'recipe' object was set up.

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe.name}}</h4>
```

**Fix**

I used the [safe navigaton operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) which guards against nulls in property paths:

```
<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{recipe?.name}}</h4>
```

**Conclusion**

There was no bug in the routing - it was an error in another part of my application which was caught in chrome - dev tools which then needed to be fixed in order to continue compiling the app

Comment: So, the error was in a section of code that you did not post in your question?

Comment: Yes - thats for that I have updated my answer with better detail